# Firebase firestore not showing my collection data and not showing any error also

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I want to get data from my Firebase Fire store database. I have a collection called categories. I am beginner in Android and would really appreciate it if someone could please help me. Here is my code.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.kuizapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loding..");
        progressDialog.show();

        FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.categoryList);
        ArrayList<CategoryModel> categories = new ArrayList<>();

        CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, categories);

        database.collection("categories")
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable 
                        FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                        categories.clear();
                        if(error!=null){
                            if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Log.d("fireStore Error", error.getMessage());
                            return;
                        }
                        for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : value.getDocuments()) {
                            CategoryModel model = snapshot.toObject(CategoryModel.class);
                            model.setCategoryId(snapshot.getId());
                            categories.add(model);
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2); //`2 spanCount`
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

**CategoryModel.java:**

```
package com.example.kuizapp;

public class CategoryModel {
    private String categoryId, categoryName, categoryImage;

    public CategoryModel(String categoryId, String categoryName, String categoryImage) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.categoryImage = categoryImage;
    }

    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public String getCategoryImage() {
        return categoryImage;
    }

    public void setCategoryImage(String categoryImage) {
        this.categoryImage = categoryImage;
    }
}
```

**CategoryAdapter:**

```
`
package com.example.kuizapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModels;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModels){
    this.context = context;
    this.categoryModels = categoryModels;

    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_category,parent,false);
        return new CategoryViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CategoryModel model = categoryModels.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(categoryModels.get(position).getCategoryName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryModels.size();
    }

    public static class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;


            public CategoryViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            }
        }
} 

`
```

[image: Firebase image]

Comment: What does `getCategoryName()` inside `onBindViewHolder` return?

Comment: should i return?@AlexMamo

Comment: Does it return the category name?

Comment: yes it returned

Comment: Then most likely it's a problem with your views, right?

Comment: i dont think so, cz when i put dummy data everything work fine but when i fetch from database that didn't work